# Bash script to rename folders recursively

Tags: bash, scripting, recursion, rename

I want to rename all my folders and folders within these folders, so that all underscores in the folder name are replaced by spaces. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 7):

The answer that uses `-execdir` is simpler, but will only work with versions of `find` that support `-execdir` such as GNU find, since [POSIX only specifies `-exec`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/find.html).

If you just want to use bash, this is surprisingly tricky to get right, since you're renaming the directories that `find` is searching through.  Even if you get the order right, by using the `-depth` option to `find`, you need to make sure you only rewrite the last component of the path with each `-exec`.  The following is a trivial variation of [one of the examples given in the Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030) and seems to work OK for me:

```
find . -depth -name "*_*" -exec bash -c 'dir=${1%/*} base=${1##*/}; mv "$1" "$dir/${base//_/ }"' _ {} \;
```

That FAQ answer has more discussion about problem of recursively naming folders which may be of interest.

---

*Update*: Since that one-liner is rather complex, it might be worth breaking it down a little in the interests of explanation.  Essentially, the `find` command is:

```
find . -depth -name "*_*" -exec bash -c [SOME-STUFF] _ {} \;
```

In other words, find all the directories which contain an underscore, and for each such directory, starting with the deepest, run the bash script `[SOME-STUFF]`, with parameter 0 as `_` (to indicate that we don't care about it) and parameter 1 as the name of the file that find found.  (`find` will substitute the filename for `{}` after `-exec`.  The `\;` just terminates the command that `-exec` runs.)

Then the `[SOME-STUFF]` part is made up of:

```
dir=${1%/*}
```

... which, using [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), will remove the shortest match for `/*` from the end of `$1` (the filename) and set `dir` to the result.  Similarly, this part:

```
base=${1##*/}
```

... removes the longest match of `*/` from the start of `$1` and sets `base` to the result.  So `base` is just the last component of the path.

Then the renaming is actually done by the `mv` command, which is:

```
mv "$1" "$dir/${base//_/ }"
```

That again uses parameter expansion, this time with the `${parameter/pattern/string}` syntax.  The filename (`$1`) is renamed to `$dir` followed by `$base` but with each underscore in `$base` replaced with a space.

Comment: What if you wanted the replacement value (space in this case) to be a variable originating from a calling script? In the ex. i've included $SOMEVAR does not work. find . -depth -name "*_*" -exec bash -c 'dir=${1%/*} base=${1##*/}; mv "$1" "$dir/${base//_/$SOMEVAR}"' _ {} \;

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply cd to /dir and :

```
find -depth -type d -execdir rename 's/_/ /g' {} \;
```

Depending of the distro, you need perl rename (sometimes prename).

If

```
file $(type -p rename)
```

output contains ELF, that looks bad ;)

**edit**
 -depth and -execdir added

Comment: This won't work because 'foo_bar' will be found and renamed before 'foo_bar/baz_quux' is output by `find` - the latter will not be found when the rename is attempted.

Comment: Not a big deal, you can add `-depth` switch to find.

Comment: It still doesn't work, I'm afraid - the first command to be called in that example is `rename 's/_/ /' ./foo_bar/bar_baz`, which gives the error `Can't rename ./foo_bar/bar_baz ./foo bar/bar_baz: No such file or directory` - if you're using `rename` you need a regular expression that will only replace the underscores in the last component of the path.

Comment: Try using `-execdir` instead of `-exec`.

Comment: Another error is that this will only replace the first underscore in the directory name - try `s/_/ /g` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you have bash4, you can run :

```
for i in **; do [[ -d "$i" ]] || continue; mv "$i" "${i/_/ }"; done
```